# Return value from inner closure

Tags: swift

Can't find a solution searching for this. Classic problem - want to find if a sum exists for any pair within an Integer array such that [1,2,3,4], 7 is true

My naive solution give the error

> Unexpected non-void return value in void function

I guess because I want to return from the inner forEach closure.

```
func pairs (_ input: [Int], _ sum: Int ) -> Bool {
    input.forEach { (number) in
        let secondInput = input.filter{$0 != number}
        secondInput.forEach{secondNumber in
            if ((secondNumber + number) == sum) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

How do I return?

Comment: you can't provide an early exit for a forEach. You need to use a regular for loop.

Comment: By the way all the answers are wrong for the problem, unless the input is unique. The only suitable answer here is that forEach does not have early exit. Full solutions should NOT be provided in this case.

Comment: @stevenpcurtis that's not nice of you to dismiss all attempts to help you. BTW, I updated my answer with a solution to this new requirement (that was not stated in the question).

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` only iterates through the given sequence, you can't return values from a `forEach` closure. `contains` is better suited for this kind of tasks:

```
func pairs(_ input: [Int], _ sum: Int ) -> Bool {
    return input.contains { number in
        let secondInput = input.filter { $0 != number }
        return secondInput.contains { secondNumber in
            return secondNumber + number == sum
        }
    }
}
```

You could also try a more functional solution, that splits the problem in multiple steps:

```
func pairs(_ input: [Int], _ sum: Int ) -> Bool {
    return input            
        .flatMap { input1 in input.map { input2 in (input1, input2) } } // build all combinations of numbers from the input array
        .contains { input1, input2 in input1 != input2 && input1 + input2 == sum } // check if a pair made of two distinct numbers adds up to the sum
}
```

If you need a solution that handles any kind of inputs (e.g. only unique numbers), then the functional solution can be adapted to this:

```
func pairs(_ input: [Int], _ sum: Int ) -> Bool {
    return input.indices
        .flatMap { i1 in input.indices.map { i2 in (i1, i2) } }
        .contains { i1, i2 in i1 != i2 && input[i1] + input[i2] == sum }
}
```

Comment: The functional solution won't work to find a sum of similar numbers. E.g, `4` in  `[0, 2, 2, 3]`

Comment: @Kamran the functional solution mirrors the code from the question, seems the OP doesn't want two identical numbers to be considered a valid pair. I have a solution that works for the scenario you described too (different indexes), but didn't post it.

Answer (score 0):

P.S Please ignore if you're only looking to get your naive solution working.

How about this? It takes time + space complexity into consideration.

I believe this should work well for a large set or arrays

```
func pairs (_ input: [Int], _ sum: Int ) -> Bool {
        var firstIndex = 0
        var lastIndex = input.count - 1
        while firstIndex != lastIndex {
            let sumCalculated = input[firstIndex] + input[lastIndex]
            if sumCalculated == sum {
                return true
            } else if sumCalculated > sum {
                lastIndex = lastIndex - 1
            }  else if sumCalculated < sum {
                firstIndex = firstIndex + 1
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Comment: This will work only for sorted arrays. For unsorted array like `[1, 3, 5, 3, 2, 2, 5, 8, 9, 5]`, this will fail to find `17`.

Comment: I agree. But the question shows a sorted array as well

Comment: A better solution shouldn't consider the only input in question i believe.